# In MySQL, how do I select only rows with certain values for a given column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table:

```
|user_id | first_name | last_name |
----------------------------------|
| 0      |  joe       |  smith    |
| 1      |  bob       |  jones    |
| 2      |  joe       |  black    |
| 3      |  mary      |  jeane    |
| 4      |  peter     |  parker   |
```

How would I go about selecting the contents of the rows which correspond to the user_id's `1`, `2` and `3`? I want to use these rows later to display their contents in a list to the user.

Comment: what result you want explain bit more

Comment: I hope its not that simple you are asking. select * from user where user_in in(1,2,3)

Comment: The given table is only an example, as my actual table is much larger with many more columns. Basically, what I want to do is pick certain rows (1,2,3... 1,3... 0,2,4... any combination really) and then be able to display just those in a list to the user.

Comment: I suggest a good SQL tutorial.  If you're looking for a book, "SQL For Dummies" is a favorite, even though I know a lot of people don't like the "For Dummies" series.

Comment: I've tried that, but it didn't work. Let me fix a few things and try again and see if that works... My apologies in advance if that really is the answer and I'm just a dunce.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
select user_id,first_name,last_name 
from your_table_name 
where user_id in (1,2,3);
```

Replace `your_table_name` with the actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

Place the comma separated column names that you want as output right after `select` keyword. 
`in` clause is used to select between multiple values. 
So in your case, query would look some how like this:

```
select user_id, first_name, last_name
from table_name
where user_id in (1,2,3);
```