# Php-Myql: select every row with same specific value

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I tried to made an autofilling html table that add or remove its rows with database. But now I need to make that the table will fill in only those rows with specific "Domain" column. For example, I have 3 table rows and in 2 of them, "domain" colum's value is "1" and the third row has "domain" column value of 1. I need to my php code to automatically choose only those rows with "1" value in "Domain" column and ignore the others. So when I add more rows to my database, the html table will only take those rows with 1 specific value.

Code:

```
<?php

$server = mysql_connect("localhost", "admin", "admin"); 
$db = mysql_select_db("rpo", $server);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suhrn");
?>

<table>
<tr>
<td>Text</td>
<td>Type</td>
<td>Zobrazit</td>
<td>DOMAIN</td>
<td>Comment</td>
 </tr>


<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   ?>
   <tr>
    <td> <?php echo $row['Popis']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['Typ']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['Zobrazit']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['Domena']; ?> </td>
   </tr>
<?php
 }
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you TRY and google? this is ever so basic stuff that it is covered in almost EVERY tutorial.

Comment: Yes i tried but i didn find it. If what you are saying is true, im blind or I cannot google. Sorry

Comment: use where condition based on your requirements

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In MySQL, how do I select only rows with certain values for a given column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13984981/in-mysql-how-do-i-select-only-rows-with-certain-values-for-a-given-column)

Comment: duplicate? Ops sorry. Its resolved now, "where" did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your problem, but maybe a slight modification to your SQL-Statement should do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM suhrn WHERE col_domain = 1;
```

Hope that helps

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it's exact based on what you wrote, but you could try that :

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM suhrn WHERE Domena=1");
```

Additionaly, you should stop using mysql_function, and use [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Yes i know i hear that i should use mysqli but, nah its working with mysql too so im happy :D.